# React does't Re-Render the App after fetching data from JSON Database

Tags: reactjs

When I open the app, useEffect successfully transfers the data to my app via fetch function and the app re-renders so that the todos are displayed.

If I create a new todo via handleCreateTodo, send it to the server via a post request and then call the fetch function, the database is updated but the app does not Re-Render. I have to refresh the browser manually so that the new todo is displayed.

```
import { FunctionComponent, ReactElement, ChangeEvent, MouseEvent, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { v4 } from "uuid";
import axios from "axios";

const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8000';


let currentTodos: Todos  [];  

export const TodoTable: FunctionComponent = (): ReactElement => {
   
   
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Array<Todos>>([]);   
    const [enterTodo, setEnterTodo] = useState<string>('');


    //Get Todos from DB
    const fetchTodos = async() => {
        const { data, status } = await axios.get(endpoint + '/todos');
        if(status == 200){
            setTodos(data);
        }
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTodos();
    }, []);


    //Enter Todo handler
    const handleEnterTodo = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
      setEnterTodo(event.currentTarget.value);
    };
  

    //Create Todo handler
    const handleCreateTodo = async () => {

        //create new Todo
        const newTodo = {
            //id: todos.length+1,
            id: v4(),
            describtion: enterTodo,
            done: false
        };

        const { status } = await axios.post(endpoint + '/todos', newTodo);
        if(status == 200){
            fetchTodos();
        }
        
        setEnterTodo('');
 
    };

    return(
            <>  
                <div className="todoTable">
                    <InputBar 
                        enterTodo={ enterTodo } 
                        handleEnterTodo={ handleEnterTodo } 
                        handleCreateTodo={ handleCreateTodo }
                        handleClearTodos= { handleClearTodos }
                    />
                    
                    <TodosDisplay 
                        todos={ todos } 
                        handleDeleteTodo={ handleDeleteTodo } 
                        handleStatus={ handleStatus }
                    /> 
                </div>    
            </>      
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

```
useEffect(() => {

},[todos])
```

If useEffect take parameter on this array, it will render when todos updated.